# input target value from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, input, ecmascript-6

I've managed to get my input component to render onto the dom, however I'm having a bit of trouble accessing the props.

Functional input component

```
const InputField = props => {
  const { inputValue, updateInputValue } = props
  return (
    <Input>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Please specify"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={updateInputValue}
      />
      <hr />
      <label>Other</label>
    </Input>
  )
}
```

The component is only rendered to the dom based on an object property inside of an array

```
const MultiChoiceQuestions = props => {
  const { multiChoiceArray, handleClick } = props
  return (
    <ButtonContainer>
      {multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => {
        if (questionChoice.type === 'input') {
          return <InputField />
        }
        return (
          <Button type="button" key={questionChoice.id} onClick={() => handleClick(questionChoice)}>
            {questionChoice.text}
          </Button>
        )
      })}
    </ButtonContainer>
  )
}
```

The multiChoice component is imported once again to create a top-level component that the app consumes

```
const Question = props => {
  let responses
  switch (props.data.type) {
    case 'multiChoice':
      responses = (
        <MultiChoiceQuestions
          multiChoiceArray={props.data.choices}
          handleClick={props.handleClick}
          inputValue={props.inputValue}
          updateInputValue={props.updateInputValue}
        />
      )
      break
    default:
      responses = <div>Error: no question type: `{props.data.type}`</div>
  }
  const { data } = props
  return (
    <AnimatedDiv key={data.id}>
      <QuestionText>{data.text}</QuestionText>
      {responses}
    </AnimatedDiv>
  )
}
```

And the final component looks like this

```
class Survey extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentQuestionId: 1,
      userAnswers: [],
      isActive: false,
      inputValue: '',
    }
    this.selectAnswer = this.selectAnswer.bind(this)
    this.test = this.test.bind(this)
  }

  selectAnswer = answer => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      currentQuestionId: state.currentQuestionId + 1,
      userAnswers: state.userAnswers.concat([answer]),
      isActive: !state.isActive,
    }))
  }



  checkInput = event => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  test = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    const { currentQuestionId, isActive, inputValue } = this.state
    const { questions } = this.props
    const currentPercentage = (currentQuestionId * 100) / questions.length
    return (
      <SurveyContainer>
        <Question
          data={questions.find(q => q.id === currentQuestionId)}
          className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}
          handleClick={this.selectAnswer}
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={this.test}
        />            
      </SurveyContainer>
    )
  }
}
```

The InputField component renders out just fine, however, the function for my onChange event is not firing...There's a mistake somewhere in the pipeline, probably inside the question component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not see where you pass props from

```
<MultiChoiceQuestions>
...
 <InputFiled props={props} />
...
</MultiChoiceQuestions>
```

Probably pass only the props which are needed in `InputField` component, such as `inputValue, updateInputValue`:

```
<InputFiled 
  inputValue={inputValue}
  updateInputValue={updateInputValue}
/>
```

```
const InputField = (inputValue, updateInputValue) => {

...
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Please specify"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => updateInputValue(e)}
      />
...

}
```

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't passed any props to `<InputField />` in your `MultiChoiceQuestions` component.